# Alternative market app without country limitations

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I want to download Apps from the US for researching purposes. A co-worker of mine could do that by installing an alternative Market. He did not have a rooted phone and probably got that app from the original market.

The icon of this app was similiar to the original market's one but blue instead of green as far as I can remember.

Answer (score 5):

I think [SlideMe](http://slideme.org) is the best Android alternative market available right now. There's an [app](http://slideme.org/en/sam2.apk) that you need to install in order to buy apps directly via your phone.

There's also [GetJar](http://getjar.com) - a number of devs are releasing their products on GetJar before or along with releasing them on the Android Market.

Comment: I think you are right about appbrain, I think I had them confused with GetJar.  +1

Comment: Tried app brain. I can see foreign apps. That's good so far. But when I hit "download" I get forwarded to my Android Market which only shows me German apps ;( I don'T want to buy stuff, just download for research.

Comment: SlideMe and GetJAR only provide apps that developers actively added to their market. However I am talking about a Market App which provides the whole content of the official Android Market in all countries.

Comment: At this time, I don't believe there is one.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is http://code.google.com/p/market-enabler/

> Market-Enabler is an application to fake the phone's location and access markets from other countries. Android market is separated into regions (country and carrier specific) and some apps are just enabled for a specific country and not available to the other countries.

Comment: I've had mixed results with this one. Didn't always work, don't know why...

Comment: Rooting required?

Comment: As far as I know rooting is required.

Answer (score 0):

The [Amazon Appstore for Android](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&ref=mas_dp&docId=1000626391) lets you buy apps via Amazon, but apparently you can only do so [if you have an American account](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/16816/11801) (I haven't tested that).