# How can I buy an app that isn't supported on my (current) device?

Tags: google-play-store

As you may know, the official Android Market is in the process of having a sale, charging only 10 cents for a bunch of apps for 10 days. They're going to pick 10 new apps each day, so the apps for sale today won't be on sale tomorrow.

I am an OG Droid owner, and I'm one of the many who is waiting to pounce on the moment the Galaxy Nexus shows up in Verizon stores. I could have upgraded my phone weeks ago, but .. well.. you know how it is.

One of the apps on sale today (Asphalt 6: Adrenaline HD) won't let me purchase it, because the Droid doesn't support it. But (hopefully) within a week I will have a phone that definitely supports this game. I don't even care if the game sucks; it's only 10 cents!

Is there any way I can buy the app anyway, so I can install it at a later date?

Comment: Do you have root access? You might be able to change the build.prop file to spoof your phone as a different device

Comment: In this case, root is not an option. I was just hoping Google would have the concept of "pay for app, but don't immediately install it". If I miss out on a few 10-cent apps that don't support the Droid 1, for just a few days (come on December 9th!), it isn't the end of the world.

Comment: Do you have a friend with a supported device? You could login to your gmail on that phone, purchase it, then remove your account when done.

Comment: I wish the answers were Market functionality and not hacks :(  That's also a theoretically good idea that isn't going to happen, Bryan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can buy it on the [Amazon android appstore](http://www.amazon.com/mobile-apps/b/ref=topnav_storetab_mas?ie=UTF8&node=2350149011). They have the same prices the Google Play. It just gives you a warning that you may be purchasing a game that does not work with your device.

and, as of today (Dec 11th 2011) its still $.10

Comment: You can only buy apps from the Amazon app store if you have an american account.

Comment: There are still some apps that are 10 cents, don't want to install on my Droid, and aren't available on the Amazon market, but it is nice to know that where there is overlap, the price is 10c on both.  Also, as a side note, I'm obviously still without my Nexus; probably won't be released during the entire 10-day sale :(

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a friend's android phone that does support the game, setting up your account in his phone and purchasing it. Be careful not to select any auto-sync features while doing so and make sure you remove the account from the phone once you've finished your purchases.

@Bryan Denny : Looks like you beat me to it :) Didn't see your comment for the question.

Comment: There apparently aren't many devices out there that support this particular game, especially with all the Nexus delays in the US. This is a less-than-ideal solution even if I had a friend with a different bleeding-edge phone. I sound like a broken record, but I find this to be a surprising missing feature from the official Market, even though it doesn't really come up except during sales like this one.

Comment: @Josh sorry a bit late as its dropped off the 10 cent list today, but you don't need a *very* new phone for Asphalt 6 HD, I got it yesterday and it installed ok on my (over a year old) original Galaxy S.