# Can I purchase apps from Android Market without installing them?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

There's currently a promo on the top 10 applications, available at barrel-bottom prices. I'd like to purchase them but not install them just yet. My phone is low on internal storage and there's just not enough space to put some of the bigger ones. I can't even attempt to install some of them (yeah, it's that bad).

I'm planning on purchasing another Android device in the near future, and those nifty apps will surely come in handy when this happens.

<sup>Please don't suggest the usual circumvention methods of moving apps to SD, installing custom ROMs, removing unused applications, etc. These either won't work or have already been done.</sup>

Comment: It won't even let you hit the "Buy" button? What if you try to buy it from the web store?

Comment: Same motivation as http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16586/how-can-i-buy-an-app-that-isnt-supported-on-my-current-device :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best you can really do currently is to buy them from the Market (web or app) and then just cancel the download/installation when it starts on your device. This only works with apps your device supports, though. Purchasing unsupported apps was the topic of [this related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16586/how-can-i-buy-an-app-that-isnt-supported-on-my-current-device).

Comment: I don't think this answer still works. Most likely the app is immediately refunded if you uninstall it. Canceling the download I would assume also end in a refund.